# How best to find duplicates and merge specific fields in a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of entities and there are certain entities that have the same name which can be considered duplicates. The collection has a column called platforms and the value for that column is an array of objects.

What i'm trying to do using $aggregate is find all of the items with the same name and then merge together what is in the platforms column so both entries have the aggregation of both platform arrays.

```
// Current entity structure in the collection
{ _id: 1, name: "Foo1", platforms: [{ _id: 1, name: "Bar" }] }
{ _id: 2, name: "Foo2", platforms: [{ _id: 7, name: "FooBar" }] }

// Required
{
  _id: 1,
  name: "Foo1",
  platforms: [{ _id: 1, name: "Bar" }, { _id: 7, name: "FooBar" }]
}

// This gets me all of the duplicates but it only shows the name and count, i don't want to lose any data that isn't simply dropping the duplicate field after the platforms have been merged.

db.titles.aggregate([
  { "$group": { "_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 }}},
  { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": null } , "count": { "$gt": 1 }}}
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unwinds and groups by name, and has 2 accumulators the array with all members and the array size. I think you dont want all member so remove it if you dont need it.

You can add the `$match` also based on your needs.

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cq4GVkjhpPV)

Query

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      "path": "$platforms"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "platforms": {
        "$push": "$platforms"
      },
      "nplatforms": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "name": "$_id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```